# How to find a leaf belongs to specific root

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, treeview

I am new to python. I am trying to access the information from the tree. Here is the input tree:

```
   +--rw service    container
   |  +--rw downstream-data-rate-profile*(list) key : name
   |  |  +--rw name                           type:bbf-yang:string-ascii64 + leaf
   |  |  +--rw maximum-net-data-rate ?        type:bbf-yang:data-rate32 + leaf
   |  |  +--rw minimum-expected-throughput ?   type:bbf-yang:data-rate32 + leaf
   |  |  +--rw maximum-gamma-data-rate ?      type:bbf-yang:data-rate32 + leaf
   |  |  +--rw minimum-gamma-data-rate ?      type:bbf-yang:data-rate32 + leaf
   |  +--rw time-division-duplexing-profile*(list) key : name
   |     +--rw name                         type:bbf-yang:string-ascii64 + leaf
   |     +--rw total-symbol-periods ?       type:uint8 + leaf
   |     +--rw downstream-symbol-periods ?   type:uint8 + leaf
   |     +--rw cyclic-extension ?           type:uint8 + leaf
```

In the above tree, 'name' is one leaf, 'maximum-net-data-rate' is another leaf which belongs to the same list: 'downstream-data-rate-profile'.

My aim is to divide the leaves as their belonging lists.
For example:

```
[name, 
maximum-net-data-rate, 
minimum-expected-throughput, 
maximum-gamma-data-rate, 
minimum-gamma-data-rate]
```

is list of leaves which belongs to the same list 'downstream-data-rate-profile'.
I need to divide like this.

Here is the code I tried:

```
with open('fast1.tree','r') as fl:
    edit=''
    f=[]
    path=[]
    clist=['container','list']
    pl=''
    f_cont=[]
    comp=['default']
    leaf_edit=[]
    for i in fl:
        f.append(i)
        if 'leaf' in i:
            cl=leaf_line=i
            c=re.search(r'[\s]([\w/.-]+)',cl).group(1)
            val=''
            f_cont=[]
            for line in f[::-1]:
                for word in clist:
                    if word in line:
                        if space(cl)>space(line):  #just comparing with the spaces
                            f_cont.append(line)
                            cl=line
            for i in f_cont:
                if 'list' in i:
                    c_l=i
                    b_list=re.search(r'[\s]([\w-]+)',i).group(1)
                    list_key = re.search(r'key :[\s]([\w-]+)',i).group(1)
                    comp.append(b_list)
                    break
            if comp[-1]==comp[-2]:  # if the last two elements are same i conclude that leaf belongs to same 'list'
                                edit = '%s '%(c)
                                leaf_edit.append(edit)
            else:
                if edit=='':
                    edit = '%s'%c
                    leaf_edit.append(edit)
                    continue
                else:
                                        print leaf_edit
                leaf_edit=[]
                edit = '%s'%c
                                leaf_edit.append(edit)
```

With this code I am able to print leaves of first list but not the last list.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Is the tree depth constant?

Comment: tree depth varies, i added here just a part of tree.